# How to fix axios not saving cookies for my user sessions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have built an api server in rails and I am now trying to obtain that data in json form using axios to make requests. This is a test set of requests. However, the cookie associated with the user session is not saved. I know that it is not caused by an issue by rails as it works when I use postman. The second route always hits me with a forbidden status

I have searched around and I know that axios has a bug with cross site requests. But when I use fetch instead, the problem persists

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: "http://localhost:3000/login",
    data: {
        email: "samples@net.com",
        password: "password"
    },
    withCredentials: true
}).then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

axios.get("http://localhost:3000/flights", {
    withCredentials: true
}).then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

In my rails controller

```
    pp "===========<LOOK HERE>==========="
    pp " =>"
    pp session[:user_id]
    pp "===========<LOOK HERE>==========="
    if current_user
      render json: flights
    else
      render json: { error: 'authentication failed' }, status: :forbidden
    end
  end
```

When I use postman, session[:user_id] returns an integer, but it returns nil when I use axios.

Comment: any mention of "CORS" errors in the browser developer console or network tabs?

Comment: Yes. originally, I was directly editing the response headers, but I am using the gem 'rack-cors'. And I modified the application.rb in config. Sorry I forgot to mention it. I know that it is the wildcard operator that is causing the issue, but now I dont know how to change to it, because when I change it to the address of the client server, it doesnt work

Comment: ahh, OK, so it's not a CORS error. Odd, because usually if postman works and javascript doesn't, it's a CORS error. If you inspect the axios request in the developer tools network tab, does it return the correct response there?

Comment: Actually I do think it is CORS now. When I add directly to my react.js server and run in the browser, I get this error:  `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.` But I have CORS enabled in rails. When I user the wildcard operator in the header, I get another error

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.` which has to do with the axios attributes, but I need those attributes

Comment: ahh, so it IS a CORS error after all - your server needs to handle CORS preflight OPTIONS request